# How to use a layout component and change the data with the ID using react redux toolkit

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a component for a layout that I am using on several pages and want to change the data depending on the page.

I have a store set up and get the data for each page right now but with 4 pages having the same layout I want to make the layout its own component. I can't figure out how to make it so it will change according to the categoryID.

below is a short part of my code.

```
const Books = () => {
const products = useSelector(state => state.products)
                return (
                     <>
                        <SideMenu/>
                          {products.map(product => (
                            <div key={product.categoryId + product.description} >
                                 {(product.sortOrder === 0 && product.categoryId === 2 )? <>
                                    <img className="img-fluid"
                                        src={product.imagePath}
                                        alt="book"
                                        id="book"
                                    />
                                    </>
                                    :<> </>}

                                <div className="mainBack">
                                {(product.sortOrder === 0) && (product.categoryId === 2) && (product.description !== null) ? <>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className=" col" 
                                                 id="description" >
                                                {product.description}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </> 
                                     : <> </>}
                    </>
export default Books;
```

I was hoping to have a Layout.js component with all the HTML and data with an ID variable I can change in another component.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `categoryId`?  Are these different categories of books, or different types of products?  What are the 4 pages?  As far as things like `<SideMenu/>`, you can create a `Layout` component that acts as a wrapper around the content using [`props.children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren).  Are all products rendered the same way, and you just want to switch *which* products are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to filter the products so that just those with `(product.sortOrder === 0) && (product.categoryId === 2)` are shown.  On a different page, you want to do the same but with a different filter.  Instead of selecting all of the products with `useSelector`, you can use a selector function to select just the products that you want.  Then we can remove those conditional checks from the JSX.

Let's make this really flexible.  First let's create a component that takes a prop `product` which is a single product and renders it in the format for a category page, probably a "tile" of some sort.

```
const ProductTile = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img className="img-fluid" src={product.imagePath} alt="book" id="book" />
      <div className="mainBack">
        {
          // is this check necessary? Do some products really have a `null` description?
          product.description !== null && (
            <div className="row">
              <div className=" col" id="description">
                {product.description}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then let's make a component that takes a prop `products` which is an array of products and renders a product listing page with these products.  This is where you include layout elements like `<SideMenu/>` etc.

```
const ProductListingPage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SideMenu />
      {products.map((product) => (
        <ProductTile
          product={product}
          // I hate this key! do you have a `product.id` that you can use?
          // needs a fallback if product.description might be null
          // but this is a problem because you will have non-unique keys
          key={product.categoryId + (product.description || "")}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

These two are what's called "presentational" components because all that they do it take data from props and present it.  They don't have any state or call any hooks.

So now we want to create a "container" component that contains the logic.  This component will take the `categoryId` as a prop.  It will select all of the products from that category and sort them according to their `sortOrder`.  It then passes those products to a `ProductListingPage` which handles the rendering.

Most of the logic is in the selector, which we can define as a separate function. I am using the [lodash `sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) function because it is easy to write and understand compared to using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparer function.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import sortBy from "lodash/sortBy";

// double arrow function takes a categoryId and returns a selector function for that category
const selectCategoryProducts = (categoryId) => 
  (state) => {
    // filter to only those that match the categoryId
    const catProducts = state.products.filter(
      (product) => product.categoryId === categoryId
    );
    // sort them by sortOrder using lodash sortBy
    return sortBy(catProducts, "sortOrder");
  };

const CategoryProductsPage = ({categoryId}) => {
  const products = useSelector(selectCategoryProducts(categoryId));
  return (
    <ProductListingPage products={products}/>
  )
}
```

Keeping `ProductListingPage` as a separate component from `CategoryProductsPage` means that you can create product listing pages with different selections of products, like the newest products regardless of category, featured products, etc.